# Ubuntu 12.04 GUI not working after installation

Tags: 12.04, boot

So, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (via Unetbootin) onto my hard drive (I did not use a live boot disk to accomplish this task). After the installation when I boot up I get 2/4 orange dots and half of the time it will say:

> could not write bytes, broken pipe

and will send me to a virtual terminal (achieved with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). I have tried commands like `service gdm3 restart` for gdm3, lightdm, kde, etc. but all I get is the service unrecognized.

I have already thought of a solution, to connect to the internet and run `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, what I would need is the command to connect to the internet. Then I could be on my way.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version? Have you tried the official method of creating a boot usb?

Comment: so you're installing system without an internet connection? what is your videocard? `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` I'm assuming your system is using nouveau by default and you might need to install the proprietary driver. `Couldn't write bytes, broken pipe` it's not that serious trouble more commonly a bug.